# Smart CVS connection reset error on Windows 7

Tags: cvs, java

I have used SmartCVS under Windows XP and Vista several years and it works fine, but after upgrading to Windows 7 it doesn't work.

Following error message is present in the SmartCVS log file:

```
[WorkerThread-1] ERROR javacvs.requestprocessor  - 
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
```

The error occurs during any operation (commit, update, compare, etc.).
I have tried to with Windows Firewall disabled, but still get this error.
After the error internet connection is gone at all, and I have to reboot the PC to have internet access.

Is there anybody who have the same problem?
Any help will useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a low-level TCP error. Try to update your network driver.

Comment: Thanks for response. It looks like the problem is connected with my network driver. As I understand there is a common problem with my network card and the Windowd 7. If anybody else has this problem please wind details by the following link: http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/5787-problems-atheros-l1-ethernet-adapter-win7-x64.html